# Redirecting with return statement influences the rendering process in next page

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, commandlink

I have a problem with the rendering of a datatable.
In my application I have this navigation bar:

```
<h:form>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
        <li class="active" role="presentation">
            <h:commandLink value="Veranstaltungen" action="#{eventController.redirect('veranstaltung.xhtml')}"/>
        </li>                       
        <li role="presentation"> 
            <h:commandLink value="Beacons" action="#{beaconcontroller.redirect('beacon.xhtml')}"/>
        </li>  
        [...]         
    </ul>
</h:form>
```

Redirect (beaconcontroller):

```
public String redirect(String link) {
    beacons = database.getAllBeacons();
    return "./" + link;
}
```

The navigation works perfectly, but when I submit the form `beaconData` in the beacon.xhtml my datatable won't be rendered.

```
<h:form id="beaconsTable">
    <p:dataTable value="#{beaconcontroller.beacons}" var="b"
        tableStyleClass="table table-striped"
        emptyMessage="Keine Beacons verfügbar"
        style="font-size:14px"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
        rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'first-row' : 'second-row'}"
        >
        <p:column style="float:left;border:none;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                   <h:commandLink actionListener="#{beaconcontroller.sortBeacons}"> 
                         <f:ajax execute="@this" render="beaconsTable"/>
                         Beacons 
                   </h:commandLink>    
            </f:facet>
            <h:commandLink>
                 <f:ajax listener="#{beaconcontroller.fillFields(b)}" execute="@this" render=":beaconData beaconsTable :delete"/>
                 <h:outputText value="#{beaconcontroller.getCompleteString(b)}" style="#{beaconcontroller.currentBeacon == b ? 'color:#337AB7' : 'color:#555555'}"></h:outputText>
            </h:commandLink>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>


</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h:form role="form" id="beaconData" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>UUID*</label>
            <h:inputText id="id_uuid" binding="#{uuidAttribute}" class="form-control" value="#{beaconcontroller.uuid}" p:placeholder="Unternehmen" required="true" requiredMessage="Bitte UUID angeben" validatorMessage="Bitte nur Zahlen und Buchstaben angeben">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z]+"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message styleClass="errMessage" for="id_uuid" style="color: red"/>
        </div>
        [...]                  
        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Speichern" actionListener="#{beaconcontroller.saveData}" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="#{beaconcontroller.currentBeacon == null}">
            <f:ajax render="beaconData :beaconsTable" execute="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Clicking on an other entry in the datatable, solves the problem. Then the table will be rendered on submit. But why dosen't it work on the first time?

When I now change `action="#{beaconcontroller.redirect('beacon.xhtml')}"` in the navigation bar to `action="beacon.xhtml"` it works all correct. I thought these expressions are meaning the same?

Comment: What is the response status? The design looks somewhat strange as you are forwarding just after getting all rows through `beacons = database.getAllBeacons();`.

Comment: How can I get the respone status?
I want to refresh the content of my variable before the page is rendered. I didn't find a better solution.

Comment: Press F12 or ctrl+shift+j and select the Network tab (Google Chrome).

Comment: Did you mean this?

Response Headers

(Source)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 01 Jun 2015 10:31:52 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

(Parsed)
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 01 Jun 2015 10:31:52 GMT
Server:GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)

Comment: I just wanted to know, if the response status is 200 OK and not 404 not found :)

Comment: Okay^^. Then it's 200 OK :D

Comment: Your setup is a little confusing. Is all the markup you've posted here on the same page? Also, what you have here is a forward, not a redirect (you need `?faces-redirect=true` attached to the destination link for a true redirect). What's the scope of `beanController`?

Comment: The first markup is in all xhtml files. The last is in one of the files. Just as an example. 

Okay, I will rename the method. Thanks :). 

The beaconController has SessionScope.